# How can I verify a email and a phone number through a single resex?

Tags: regex, entity-framework, email, asp.net-mvc-4, phone-number

Well, I have 2 separate regex for verification email and phone number separately. Like

```
email = "^\w+\@([\da-zA-Z\-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,6}"
```

and

```
phone = "^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}"
```

However,  I want to input input form a field which may b either email and Phone. And I must validate them. 
I have tried using a || operator for or between those two resex, but didn't work.

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\w+\@([\da-zA-Z\-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,6} || ^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone number Email Address")]
[Display(Name = "Phone number or Email")]        
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsUserExists", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "This Phone number or Email already exists")]
public string MobOrEmail { get; set; }
```

So I need a proper regex which can verify both email or a phone number at a time. Or an or operation between them will be perfect and I need it badly. Thanks.

Comment: You need a single `|` character for `OR` (not 2)

Comment: I have tried using a single pipe (|) but it's not working for both, it's just working for email only.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I think that qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @lazycoder Are you adding a space after the area code? I noticed it requires a dash.

Comment: Refer [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3flag) - works fine. But as a side note, that is a very poor regex for an email address

Comment: I am afraid @JackHasaKeyboard, I didn't understand what you exactly said. Where shall i put a space, I am poor in regex, I don't understand what is area code.

Comment: @lazycoder The "area code" is the first part of the phone number. Your current regex requires that it's connected with a dash (555-555-5555) and I was asking if you were trying to match it against a phone number that had a space there (555 555-555). It worked fine for me when I tested it against the example with the dash.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, Yes!!! you referred link is working exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single `|` (pipe) character (not 2) and without the spaces. It should be

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\w+\@([\da-zA-Z\-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,6}|[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "...")
```

Refer [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3flag)

Note that you email regex is not very strong. The one used by `jquery.validate.js` is

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$
```

To make this a bit easier to read in the model, and easier to reuse, you could create your own attribute that extends `ReqularExpressionAttribute`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EmailOrPhoneAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{

    public EmailOrPhoneAttribute () : base(@"^\w+\@([\da-zA-Z\-]...etc")
    {
        // Add default error message
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone number Email Address";
    }
}
```

and register it in `global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ....
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(EmailOrPhoneAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
    ....
}
```

and then in the model

```
[EmailOrPhone]
public string MobOrEmail { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you combine both phone number and jQuery email in a single regex?

Comment: Sure, You can just use the jquery regex above and add the `|[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}` to the end in your `RegularExpressionAttribute` (but you would not be able to use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute since that would prevent the phone number.

Comment: Makes for a very long attribute though, so you might want to consider creating an attribute from `RegularExpressionAttribute` - say `[EmailOrPhone(ErrorMessage = "...")]` and registering it `global.asax`

Comment: I was thinking so. Because this regex expression is too large to handle. I prefer to write in `Global.asax` rather than `Mode`.

Comment: Yeah!! I have already finished. Any way. thanks for your support.